# What does AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk' mean?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner at programming and am writing a simple game of hangman with tkinter and do not know how to solve the error.

```
             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ana/Documents/primer7.py", line 62, in <module>
    class MyGUI():
  File "/Users/ana/Documents/primer7.py", line 93, in MyGUI
    tkinter.mainloop()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 405, in mainloop
    _default_root.tk.mainloop(n)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

can you help me with the solution?
overall the code should be fine, does anybody have any suggestions how to make it even easier/simple? or how to make better GUI (buttons), I do not understand it very well?

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import random

#fruit category
easyWords = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'peach', 'guava']
#space category
mediumWords = ['atmosphere', 'jupiter', 'quasar', 'satellite', 'asteroid']
#science category
hardWords = ['biochemical', 'hemoglobin', 'emulsify', 'reactant', 'dynamo']

def setting():

    wordChoice = ''

    difficulty = input('''Welcome to hangman, select your difficulty.
Type, easy, medium, or hard to begin:''')

    if difficulty == 'easy':

        wordChoice = easyWords.random
        print('You have selected easy mode, start guessing your letters now in the game window. The category is: fruit')

    if difficulty == 'medium':

        wordChoice = mediumWords.random
        print('You have selected medium mode, start guessing your letters now in the game window. The category is: space')

    if difficulty == 'hard':

        wordChoice = hardWords.random
        print('You have selected hard mode, start guessing your letters now in the game window. The category is: science')

def game():

    missGuess = 0
    guesses = ''

    for char in wordChoice:
        label3.print(char),

        if char in guesses:
            print(char),

        else:
            label3.print("_"),
            missGuess += 1

        if missGuess == 1:
            label1.print('head')
        if missGuess == 2:
            label1.print('torso')
        if missGuess == 3:
            label1.print('left arm')
        if missGuess == 4:
            label1.print('right arm')
        if missGuess == 5:
            label1.print('left leg')
        if missGuess == 6:
            label1.print('right leg'),

class MyGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.tk()

        #create needed frames
        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.center_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        #create top frame labels
        self.label1 = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame,  text='Hangman parts:')
        self.label2 = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame,  text=' ')
        #center frame labels
        self.label3 = tkinter.Label(self.center_frame,  text=' ')
        #bottom frame labels
        self.label4 = tkinter.Label(self.bottom_frame,  text='Guess a letter:')
        self.entry1 = tkinter.Entry(self.bottom_frame, width=5)
        self.button1 = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,  text='Guess', command=self.game) #calls the game method
        self.button2 = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,  text='Exit',  command=self.main_window.destroy)

        #pack top frame labels
        self.label1.pack(side='left')
        self.label2.pack(side='right')
        #pack center frame
        self.label3.pack(side='top')
        #bottom frame
        self.label4.pack(side='left')
        self.entry1.pack(side='left')
        self.button1.pack(side='left')
        self.button2.pack(side='left')

    tkinter.mainloop()

setting()
main()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more meaningful. Your title should describe the problem you're having or question you're asking, and should contain information that will be useful when seen in a list of search results by future users of this site. Your current title contains nothing at all descriptive or meaningful. Thanks.

Comment: It means your variable is None, but you expect it to be some object. You need to figure out why your variable is None.

Comment: Giving us the full traceback will be appreciated

Comment: This error means you are trying to launch the `mainloop()` on the wrong object, `tkinter` is the module, not a class you can use to display a widget.
You should better instantiate a `tkinter.Tk()` object outside the class (move the `self.main_window = tkinter.tk()`) and apply the `mainloop()` on it. The rest of the code needs several fixes, take it step by step... btw, `label1.print('some text')` cannot work, you must change this to `label1.config(text='some text')`

Answer (score 0):

`mainloop()` should be called on a `tkinter.Tk()` instance. Change this line:

```
tkinter.mainloop()
```

to:

```
self.main_window.mainloop()
```

Also, indent the line properly under the `__init__` method in the `MyGUI` class.

So `MyGUI` becomes:

```
class MyGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.tk()

        #create needed frames
        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.center_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        #create top frame labels
        self.label1 = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame,  text='Hangman parts:')
        self.label2 = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame,  text=' ')
        #center frame labels
        self.label3 = tkinter.Label(self.center_frame,  text=' ')
        #bottom frame labels
        self.label4 = tkinter.Label(self.bottom_frame,  text='Guess a letter:')
        self.entry1 = tkinter.Entry(self.bottom_frame, width=5)
        self.button1 = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,  text='Guess', command=self.game) #calls the game method
        self.button2 = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame,  text='Exit',  command=self.main_window.destroy)

        #pack top frame labels
        self.label1.pack(side='left')
        self.label2.pack(side='right')
        #pack center frame
        self.label3.pack(side='top')
        #bottom frame
        self.label4.pack(side='left')
        self.entry1.pack(side='left')
        self.button1.pack(side='left')
        self.button2.pack(side='left')

        self.main_window.mainloop()
```

I hope it helps.

As a side note, `MyGUI` is not called anywhere in your code, and the `main` function is also not available in the submitted code. I don't know the logic of your game so what I did just addresses the error message, the rest is up to you to address.

Comment: Your first remark is debatable. As is, the `mainloop` function is called within the `MyGUI` class, which makes very little sense, so I'm not sure this can be rationally discussed. Besides, the `tkinter.mainloop` *module function* can be called instead of the `mainloop` *instance method* of the first widget created.